# blank space in right of my site at mobile version

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a webpage. I am the first to admit my CSS skills are not the best.

There is blank space appearing to the right side of the mobile version page. ([www.perfectshinesmile.com](http://www.perfectshinesmile.com))

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your container is not picking up margin:0 auto in mobile css.

So replace from **main.css at line number 2638**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 641px)
.container {
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 0;
}
```

**to**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 641px)
.container {
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: On browser, look ok, but check from mobile please! What it`s problem?

Comment: After checking your website .. I find a lot of errors !! You surely hire someone to do the fix because the css is not stable at all and there are lott of things to be fixed..

Comment: There are plenty (I mean plenty) of edits to fix the things for the result you need. Sorry I can't provide you all the fixtures here as its a big task !! hope you can fix them by yourself or hire someone ;) . No offence but the css is just very poorly written and not according to the standards at all .

Comment: Thank you! But in this moment i don`t have money to hire somebody, what can i need to edit? can you give me some details please?

Comment: Or some code to block right space to this version? Exist one short method?

Comment: yes surely.. The right space is coming because of the fixed width that you have given almost everywhere .. If you can reduce those fixed width to around 300px or so or just use  percentages like giving 360px width to 100% that will be a solution..

Comment: Sorry, but i`m not sure what i need to make. I need to make width of body,html use percentages to give me 360 width?

Comment: I resolve problem with this code:                                                                              html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}             Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your `.container` has set `max-width` property to 360px. Change it to `max-width: none`. But I reccomend you to your [bootsrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for web layout, you would avoid such a problems. I can see in your code that a lot of elements has specific width value, resulting to broken layout on mobile devices.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn`t work, check my website from mobile please!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have a second scroll bar!

or you do this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none !important;}
```

Or you do this

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 641px){
    .section {
        min-height: auto;
        width: 360px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

Don't use the overflow:scroll; ever unless you need it! especially in phones port!